# Multicore Processing Python dosent print the output of a function

Tags: python

I don't understand why is the reason that the code dosen't print the output in console of this very fool programm.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process

def calc2(nucleo, tope):
    for i in range(0, tope):
        print(str(np.sqrt(i)) + "  el nucleo es  " + str(nucleo))


processes = []

for i in range(os.cpu_count()):
    print("registering process %d" % i)
    processes.append(Process(target=calc2, args=(i, 100, )))

for process in processes:
    process.start()

for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

Comment: After I added `import os; import numpy as np` to this script, it worked as expected. I can't reproduce the issue of not having output. Is your script really missing those imports? Does it output anything at all? How are you running it?

Comment: when i run this to my python console doesn't print any output

Comment: I refer to the output from the calc2 function that is the form

      print(str(np.sqrt(i)) + "  el nucleo es  " + str(nucleo))

Comment: What do you mean by "python console"? The command line? Multiprocessing doesn't work in all environments, especially things like the interactive python shell console on windows.

Comment: I am running this program with the IDE Spyder, I wrote the code and launched

Comment: Try it from the command line and see if that works.

Comment: Ok, I will try it, but i have some interesting questions about the MP library,
1) How can I pass the results from the function output to the main?, for example

`code`(    
def    funtion():
         process...
         return variable_a

def main():
      proc = Process(traget=funtion)
      proc.start())

Comment: There are multiple ways to return values. In your case a process pool and the `map` method instead of managing your own processes is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

As for how to get return values, here is one option

```
import os
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

def calc2worker(args):
    return calc2(*args)

def calc2(nucleo, tope): 
    return ["{} el nucleo es {}".format(np.sqrt(i), nucleo)
        for i in range(0, tope)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = mp.Pool() # defaults to os.cpu_count()
    data_generator = ((i, 100) for i in range(os.cpu_count()))
    for result in pool.map(calc2worker, data_generator):
        for line in result:
            print(line)
    pool.close()
```